# Nested IFERROR, VLOOKUP, IF VBA code + copy down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code to do this formula:
`=IFERROR(Vlookup(C3,PasteValues!$A:$F,6,0),IF(Q2="","",Q2))`
I also want to copy this formula down into the entire column.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Range("P:P").Copy Range("Q:Q")
LastRow = Range("P2:P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Range("C2"),Range("TableEmail!A:F"),6,FALSE),IF(Q2="","",C2))
```

When I tried this, the formula did not copy down/returned syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the formula it must be a string.  One only uses `Application.WorksheetFunction` when wanting to use that function to return a value in vba.  If what is wanted is to place the formula in a cell, or range, using `.Formula` then the formula is a string in US-EN format with any `"` inside the string doubled:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    .Range("P:P").Copy .Range("Q:Q")
    LastRow = .Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,TableEmail!A:F,6,FALSE),IF(Q2="""","""",C2))"
End With
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm new to VBA. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Hey Scott, I'm still not getting the code to work. Instead of the value going into Row 2, it goes into Row 1, and it doesn't work as a formula as there is no "=" sign in front. It is not copying down either. Any other ideas?

Comment: @kaytea11 please see latest edit.  BigBen found the error.